# Is there a way to determine if an MSMQ queue is local?

Tags: .net, msmq

When processing an acknowledgement message, the `Message.ResponseQueue` could be from a local private queue and thus the `MessageQueue.FormatName` will be in the form: "PRIVATE=d1e5a3cf-4631-4a04-bb05-1fb20eb2c421\0000001a" when the original queue FormatName was in the form of "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:MyMachine\private$\myqueue".

Is there a way to:
1) Detect that this queue is local.
2) Convert "PRIVATE=d1e5a3cf-4631-4a04-bb05-1fb20eb2c421\0000001a" to "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:MyMachine\private$\myqueue"

I assume I could simply parse the FormatName and if it is in this form "PRIVATE=d1e5a3cf-4631-4a04-bb05-1fb20eb2c421\0000001a" then it is local and then by default if it is local the Label is the original FormatName used to connect to it.

Is this a valid assumption?